# How to update different values in same column in mysql in single query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a table name test with two column id and count in mysql db.
I want to do similar like below in single query(I know this is not working).

```
UPDATE test
SET 
    count = (1, 2, 3)
WHERE
    id IN (5, 8, 9);
```

I can use `CASE` when count and id are fixed but in my case they change so i cant use that.
Given example they have 3 values but it could varies between 1 to 10.
Please help if anyone knows how to do this in single query.

Comment: Given that you have to rewrite the query anyway when you change the values, why can't you use a `CASE` statement?

Comment: @Nick because it is not necessary that i will get same count and id pair count.I mentioned that in question. Pair count could vary between 1 to 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a derived table in the query:

```
UPDATE test t JOIN
       (SELECT 1 as cnt, 5 as id UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 as cnt, 8 as id UNION ALL
        SELECT 3 as cnt, 9 as id
       ) x
       ON t.id = x.id        
    SET count = x.cnt;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a lot of pairs of values, one solution would be to store them in a separate table, and then join it in the update query:

```
update test t
inner join mapping m on m.id = t.id
set t.count = m.count
```